# Swift: Media Queries not respected in WKWebView

Tags: css, ios, swift

I am attempting to write a reader mode for my iOS app that uses the `WKWebView` added as a subview to a `viewController`. However, my implementation seems to ignore the media queries inside the css.

I have a local `html` file in the app that acts as a template, and the css is like so:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>

        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) {
            body {
                max-device-width: 520px;
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
```

The intend is to center the content with a maximum width of 520px like in any response web design if displayed on large screen (ie iPad). However, my implementation still stretches edge to edge.

I have also attempted to use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of the above `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` but still yielded the same result.

Note that the above media queries behave correctly if displayed on browser, but somehow not in `WkWebView`.

EDIT

See screenshot when displayed on an iPad 12.9 simulator. I am using a splitViewController, and notice that the textual content still spreads edge to edge. This is definitely larger than 520px.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code, using min-width and max-width worked perfectly for text, but for img/other elements you probably need to define them one by one. Let me know if that solves your problem.

```
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
          @media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
              body {
                  max-width: 520px;
                  margin: 20px auto;
              }

              img {
                  max-width: 520px;
                  height: auto;
              }
          }
      </style>
</head>
```

Just confirmed it also works on splitViewController
[image]

Try the following code and it should work:

```
let string =
"""
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
          @media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
              body {
                  font-size: 16px;
                  max-width: 520px;
                  margin: 20px auto;
              }

              img {
                  max-width: 520px;
                  height: auto;
              }
          }
      </style>
</head>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
</p>
"""
        myWKWebView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work even for textual content. Are u able to share a screenshot using an iPad 12.9 inch simulator?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my implementation